# Exactly position an image

Tags: graphics, floats

I have an image that I want to postition between 2 pieces of text, however it is placing itself right at the end of the page.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,color,graphicx,float}
\geometry{a4paper}

\begin{document}
    SOME TEXT

    \begin{figure}[!H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=300pt]{image.pdf}
        \caption{capt}
    \end{figure}

    BLAH BLAH BLAAH

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show an image of the output? You should actually drop the `!`.

Comment: @Werner actually you should make that the answer (`!` before the `H` inhibits the `H` mechanism)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Removing the ! did indeed fix it.

Comment: See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491485/place-image-in-exact-position-of-the-page/576954) for exact control on where to put the image on the page, without changing the text layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)'s `H` figure positioning parameter inhibits floats from floating by setting its contents in a box and outputting it immediately. However, for it to function properly, it has to be the only placement specifier. So, use

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  %...
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why should one put some content into a float environment and then prevent this environment from floating?

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: True - an age-old question. The only motivation is that it conforms to the remainder of the document structure (figures are placed in `figure` environments to allow for proper captioning and LoF/LoT placement.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig They should not. Figures and tables belong to the top of the page or to a seperate page (with some possible rare exceptions). But it is impossible to explain this to some people...

Comment: @tohecz I have only just switched from word to LaTeX, and a google search told me to use `figure` for images, so I did.

Comment: @handuel And Google was correct of course. The problem is that in general, it is advised to let the floats to float to the top of the page. I usually don't specify any placement with a float, which usually means `[tbp]` (but in a template I manage, it's `[tp]` since I dislike bottom figures).

Comment: @tohecz: I agree. And I'm always surprised when this sledgehammer method with »[float](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)« is suggested. Consistency is not really a reasonable argument for me in this case. And there are many reasons *not* to use this package anymore. I would consider it obsolete.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative solution to David Carlisle's suggestion, is not to use the `figure` environment. (Since you don't really want a float). Try this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry,color,caption,lipsum}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
        \lipsum[1]

       {
            \centering
            \includegraphics{test.jpg}
            \captionof{figure}{capt}
        }

       \lipsum[1]

    \end{document}
```

Since you want the image centered you need to include it in a group and I have added the `captionof` from the `caption` package for the caption.

Comment: My opinion is that if a figure *must* go in a precise place, then it doesn't need a caption.