# place image in exact position of the page

Tags: graphics

I have a page of text formatted in LaTeX and I want to place an image in some position of the page, so that it doest not change the text layout by any means - I mean as if I printed the page and glued an image in the place I wish.
Is it possible to do it with LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Yes, this is possible with Ti*k*K (for instance) using `overlay,remember picture`. Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at (current page.center){\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot It is Ti*k*Z not Ti*k*K :)

Comment: We could rename it: `Ti*k*K ist *kein* Koala`. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Let's wait till we know what the OP really wants. They could be looking for `eso-pic` or something like this.

Comment: The TikZ function with overlay, remember picture works great, thanks :) Now I need to figure out how to change the position, but it should not be a problem. Thanks again :D

Comment: @marmot From the last OP's comment, you guessed!

Comment: @CarLaTeX https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with TikZ alone:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [shift={(-6cm, -3.5cm)}, rotate=35] at (current page.north east)
        { \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{stamp.png} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Given the [stamp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofi7b.png), this produces:

[image: under investigation stamp superimposed on lorem ipsum text]

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to absolute positioning of an image at a specific spot of the page, the `tikzpagenodes` package, which loads `tikz`, is often useful. It knows the `text area` and other things. One can use `xshift` and `yshift` to place the image away from some standard anchor by a specified distance.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
\node[anchor=north] at ([yshift=-1cm]current page text area.north){\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 to your crystal ball!